# Ghost pivot fields remain in PivotTable, but are not in data

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have this code :

```
Sub RvsP()
    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField
    Range("A1").Select

    Set objTable = Sheet2.PivotTableWizard
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Real Resolution Provided to Client")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Priority")
    objField.Orientation = xlColumnField
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Priority")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Real Resolution Provided to Client")
    pf.DataRange.Cells(1).Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, _
    False, False, True, False, False)

 End Sub
```

The pivot run smooth well.

But the problem is when I open a new workbook, even it has no data in its worksheet, when I run this macro the last pivot data generated still remains.

How can I totally clear them using VBA code?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or explain more what do you mean by `last pivot data generated still remain`? Do you mean that the data field `Priority` is already present on the next Pivot Table that you create?

Comment: OK, like this....
    1. I start the laptop then directly open New Workbook
    2. Then I immediately run Sub RvsP() Macro.
    3. The result was the Pivot Table from the project that I've done a week before. 
It should be empty/no pivot created right?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are saying, because in facts, your code will generate a new pivot table based on data coming from `Sheet2`. Now if it is a *new **empty** workbook, you should have an error* on `Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Real Resolution Provided to Client")` because that field cannot be found without this specific header's name! So *if your code execute without errors, it means that you have some data and you can't/won't have an empty pivot table* at the end... So it is just **unclear what you are trying to achieve**... Do you want to create an empty pivot table?

Comment: I'm also thinks the same.. It should produce some error.. But it runs smoothly.. This is a new Workbook with no data on any Sheet in it.. But I tried to run the macro from previous project (means the previous excel), the data still remain. 
The macro save at Personal.xslb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Set objTable = Sheet2.PivotTableWizard
```

You have mentioned Sheet2. So It is taking values from sheet2.
Check the data in the sheet2

Change it to

```
Set objTable = Sheet3.PivotTableWizard
```

Please check in project window

Comment: I'm opening new Worksheet project n directly run the RvsP macro. But the pivot still remain.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. New Workbook.

Comment: Is it possible to attach the file and with sample values

Comment: how can I attach the file? I dunno

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the "Missing Item Limit" to None (can be done in the properties of Pivot Table manually too) with those lines :

```
    objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
    objTable.PivotCache.Refresh
```

Sorry for the French screenshot, I can't switch language on that computer, but here is where the manual option is :

1. Click on the Pivot Table
2. Go to the Options pane, personally I use the Ribbon (it's on the left)
3. Choose the DATA tab
4. Set the `Number of items to retain ...`  to `None`
5. That should be all

[image]

So test this :

```
Sub RvsP()
    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField
    Range("A1").Select

    Set objTable = Sheet2.PivotTableWizard
        objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
        objTable.PivotCache.Refresh

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Real Resolution Provided to Client")
        objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Priority")
        objField.Orientation = xlColumnField
        objField.Orientation = xlDataField

    Set objField = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Real Resolution Provided to Client")
        objField.DataRange.Cells(1).Group _
            Start:=True, _
            End:=True, _
            Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: On the first or second table? because only the first had his parameters changed. The one described by `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)` doesn't (except if they are the same...)